# "Am I guaranteed to received the order by today?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I was trying to communicate with the customer representative to see if I can expect to receive my order by the end of the day. I wonder if the following sentences sound natural

> 1. Am I guaranteed to received the order by today?
> 2. Will I be guaranteed to received the order by today?
> 3. Am I going to be receiving the order by today?

Comment: First, none of your sentences are grammatically correct, yet I shall explain to you. *"Am I guaranteed to have received the order by tomorrow?*, which would be answered to " Yes sir, You are guaranteed to (have) receive(d) the order by tomorrow. By the way, the most natural way to say your intention is : ***Is it a guarantee that I will have the order received by tomorrow? "***

Comment: @AlexRaw Your example does not strike me as natural. I would suggest something less wordy: "Will I receive the order today/tomorrow?"

Comment: @Wehage Agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples there are some grammar problems.  The infinitive "to receive" is never "received" There is no past tense of an infinitive, though a perfective infinitive "to have received" is possible

Your question however included a useful phrase "by the end of today". It is better to use a specific time in a "by" phrase instead of a duration. So

> Am I guaranteed to receive my order by the end of today?

This question is quite harsh and demanding.  You are asking for a binding promise. Sometimes this is what you want to say (if, for example, the company had been difficult and evasive in the past), but it is easier to ask:

> When will I receive my order?

or

> Will I receive my order today?

Answer (score 0):

Is delivery today guaranteed? You don't need to mention the order. It seems redundant.